# GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon was not provided by any .service files

Tags: gnome, display, services, dbus, gnome-settings-daemon

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.6 with FVWM window manager. As far as I remember, I had gnome desktop (maybe I removed gnome) and I installed FVWM. I connect a display screen to my laptop VGA port. But the screen doesn't show anything. I go to system tools:

[image: System settings]

And I go to **Displays** and I turn my screen on:

[image: Second screen is turned on]

But when I click on **Apply** button, I receive this error:

[image: Error]

> GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon was not provided by any .service files

Does anybody know why?

Comment: You use a gnome program for konfiguration?

Comment: @nobody I just go to the applications menu and I use the available system tools. For some reason, they happen to be gnome system tools. Not sure why.

Comment: I'am not familiar with fvwm,  But fvwm do not respect the settings from gnome-tools.  Maybe you found something here http://www.fvwm.org/

Comment: Here is the solution of this problem
https://youtu.be/34iXHWuhsss